# Final render is too noisy

Tags: rendering, noise-reduction, denoise

I've started tinkering with Blender a few days ago and finally produced my own rendered image.

The only problem is that the final render is way too noisy to use.

It took around 1-2 hours to complete and I even tried to use a [denoiser addon](https://remington.pro/software/blender/d-noise/), but it didn't seem to do too well.

Are there any suggestions that could help with the final result? I can attach the blend file as well if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Please make an effort to find the answer before asking. You should try to do at least a quick search on this site to avoid duplicate questions. Also with your future questions, please post all the images in your post using the tools this platform provides instead of posting links to them. It saves a lot of time for people who are interested in helping you and you will probably get better results if you make it easier for those who try to help. The images also remain here for other people who have similar problems to find then while links you post may expire in the future.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry I don't understand how this site works yet. I found the answer. I hadn't set clamping correctly and was getting major 'fireflies'. Setting; indirect and direct lighting to 1.5 seemed to eliminate the problem altogether. I'm getting much cleaner renders now.

Comment: Check [ask], [answer] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site.